# Symfony 3 деплой и развертывание проекта на сервере

Tags: symfony3

Какой способ лучше всего подходит для деплоя symfony3 проекта? Как это сделать по чистому ftp?
Прогуглив, наткнулся на Capifony, но по идеи он не работает с третьей версией symfony.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.Вариант**

[Symfony Deployment Basics](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html)

Типичные шаги при развертывании приложения `Symfony` включают в себя:

1. Вы можете добавить свой код на сервер используя какой нибудь `FTP` клиент.Например `FileZilla`
2. Установите ваши зависимости для vendor (как правило, делается с
   помощью `Composer` и может быть сделано перед загрузкой).
3. Запуск миграции базы данных или аналогичные задачи по обновлению
   структуры изменения данных.
4. Очистка кэша.

Развертывание может также включать в себя другие задачи, такие как:

1. Пометка определенную версию вашего кода в качестве выхода в
   репозитории управления исходными кодами
2. Создание временного плацдарма для построения настроек обновлений "в
   автономном режиме - offline"
3. Выполнение каких-либо тестов, доступных для обеспечения кода и / или
   стабильность работы сервера
4. Удаление любых ненужных файлов из `web/directory`, чтобы
   сохранить производственную среду,то бишь `environment` в чистоте.
5. Очистка внешних систем кэш-памяти (как `Memcached` или `Redis`).

**2.Вариант**

Все это сделать локально а потом с помощью Source Control (**Git**,**Tortoise**)
залить на сервер.

**3.Вариант**

Есть также инструменты, чтобы помочь облегчить "боль" развертывания. Некоторые из них были специально адаптированы к требованиям Symfony.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#using-build-scripts-and-other-tools